# Duplicate AppController cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

for my site I need to have two different auth session because one login is for admin section (like worpdress admin "wp-admi" access), and one login is for account login into the site.

So I have thought to duplicate AppController with AppAdminController but I retrieve some error.

This is my AppAdminController

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppAdminController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session'); //'DebugKit.Toolbar'
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authError' => 'Questa risorsa non sembra appartenere al tuo account, oppure non hai eseguito l\'accesso',
            'autoRedirect' => false,
            'authorize' => array(
                'Controller',
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers'
                )
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'username')
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function afterFilter () {

    }

    public function beforeFilter () {

    }
}
```

and I use it into AdminController:

```
App::uses('AppAdminController', 'Controller');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class AdminController extends AppAdminController {
    public $name = 'Admin';
    public $scaffold;
    public $uses = 'users';
    public $useDbConfig = 'admin';

    public function beforeFilter () {
        parent::beforeFilter(); 

        $user_type = 'guest';

        if($this->Session->read('is_logged')){
            $auth_user = $this->Auth->user();
            $user_type = $auth_user['group'];
        }

    }
}
```

I retrieve this error:

```
Call to a member function read() on a non-object
```

into this line:

```
if($this->Session->read('is_logged')){
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think you'd need two AppController's.  What you're describing is very common and is usually dealt with using a Role  (User.role_id)  And 'admin_' routes.

Comment: No is different because I used two different database, one for admin section and one for site because we have an admin section in cloud, so I used two different database, sometimes database for site isn't exist because sites are static, but admin part to manage other thing is always present @Dave

Comment: Can you not just build 2 separate apps then?  Or even if not, just change your database depending if it's 'admin_' prefix or not.

Comment: Yes I thought to separate in 2 apps but I hope that there is a way to do it in a simple way